# How to exclude an area for keydown?

Tags: jquery, keydown

I would like to catch a pressed key in a div (using tabindex) but not when an input text inside the div is focused. I tried using .not() of jquery, but it doesn't work actually:

```
$('#content').not('input[type=text]').keydown( function(e) {
console.log(e.which);    
});
```

Here the example. https://jsfiddle.net/kz6es4h0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `event.target` to see if it was the `input` element that raised it, and stop the processing if so. Try this:

```
$('#content').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName == 'INPUT')
        return;

    console.log(e.which);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kz6es4h0/1/)

Alternatively, you can attach a separate event handler to the `input` to stop the event propagation on the `keydown` event:

```
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kz6es4h0/2/)

Comment: using target is perfect, but do you know why it doesn't work using .not()?

Comment: It's because the event propagates. The `not()` excludes attaching the event hook to the `input`. However the event still bubbles up to the parent `div` and is caught there

Comment: Ohhh okay, I got it! Thank you very much. I wasn't thinking to the propagation.

Comment: Sorry if I bother you, but I have a doubt. I understood why .not() wasn't working but considering that I'm attaching keydown to the div, and considering the bubbling propagation, it should propagates from the div to the outside excluding so the input tag. Why it's not excluded?
(I know enough jquery but I never looked to event propagation, bubbling and capturing concepts, I looked at them right now so sorry for my ignorance).

Answer (score 0):

I would put an if statement in the event listener callback to check if the input has focus at the moment

```
$('#content').keydown( function(e) {
    var hasFocus = $("input").is(":focus");
    if (!hasFocus){
        console.log(e.which);
    }
});
```

Comment: I prefer the solution of Rory McCrossan that uses event.target that allows me to not use another selector.